# How to find reference point in a object for measurement purpose using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

[Input image to find reference point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Dt1.png)

My problem statement is i want to measure the length of drill bit. so if i get two ref points automatically then i will apply euclidean-distance formula for distance measurement.

In that image, Two red points are there. That two red points are manually marked. When I place the drill bit on the belt, it automatically wants to get the points.

I was hoping you could give me your ideas, related links, and sample codes. I'm using OpenCV on Python 3.8

Comment: this question isn't new. please link to previous times you asked this question.

Comment: This is my first question in stack overflow then how to I link to previous times.

Comment: Strangely, someone posted the same question before under a similar name... https://stackoverflow.com/q/73137625/1196549

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/find-the-length-of-the-dril-bits-in-different-size/9667 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73122390/how-to-calculate-the-lengthinches-or-millimeter-of-dril-bit-using-opencv-pytho

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

### Auto-mark terminal point

1. Convert BGR image to grayscale
   `gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`
2. Use Blur methods to remove noise.
   `median = cv2.medianBlur(gray, size)`
3. Since only the drill is in dark black, you can easily use Threshold method to get drill shape.
   `img_thresh = cv2.Threshold(median,threshold_value,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)`
4. Use findContours to get drill's contour
   `contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)`
   Assume only drill left after threshold, select the biggest one as drill. Otherwise you need to use some condition to choose which contour is drill.
5. Use cv2.minAreaRect to get minimum rect which bound shape.
   `rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[0])`
   And then you can easily get pixel length of drill by rect's length, if you still want to mark the end points, you can test which points are on the short edge of rect, or just mark the middle point of short edge to get the approximate position.

### Calculate pixel length to real world length

There are several way to implement, depends on different situation and how much accuracy you want.

- Suppose drill are all in standard length - the easiest way
  You don't need to calculate the actual length between points, you can create a table which mapping pixel length to standard length. After you get pixel length, choose the closest standard length by mapping table.
- No restrictions but most complex way

1. Do camera calibration to correct camera distortion and get camera's intrinsic parameters.
   https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html
   use them to get non-distortion image before you calculate the pixel length.
   `dst = cv.undistort(img, mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)`
2. Since camera is hard to vertical to the plane, you have to calculate the coordinate relationship between image and real world.
   Put calibration board on table, the board is best to be put on the same height with drill's end point. Use intrinsic/extrinsic matrix to calculate pixel coordinate of image to real world coordinate. And then you can use the terminal point pixel coordinate calculated above to get real world position and use euclidean-distance to get distance. If you assume camera is vertical to the plane. You can directly use ruler or calibration board to calculate the scale of pixel to real world.